# How to compare a date with array of dates in SQL query and update a field value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a task where I need to find the expected date to resolve a ticket using `createdAt` and `sla_name` fields values. After that I need to compare the this `expected date` with the dates in `holidays` table.

If the `expected date` falls in `holidays`, I need to extend the `sla_name` field value.

This is the query am using.

```
SELECT t.sla_meet, t.tid, t.ticket_id, t.ticket_name,t.createdAt,t.updatedAt,t.status, dw.dropdown_name 
        as ticket_priority,p.project_name, dw3.dropdown_name as ticket_status,t.sla as sla_name, 
        isn.issue_name as issue_type,inn.incidentName as incident_type,t.ticket_accepted_date,
        t.asset_id,t.ticket_closed_date,t.contact_number, 
        IF(NOW() <= DATE_ADD(t.createdAt,INTERVAL (t.sla)+1 DAY),'YES','NO') AS slaMeetData 
        from tickets t 
        JOIN assets ast ON t.asset_id=ast.asset_id 
        JOIN projects p ON p.project_id=ast.project_id 
        JOIN admin_dropdowns dw ON t.ticket_priority=dw.id 
        JOIN admin_dropdowns dw3 ON t.ticket_status=dw3.id 
        JOIN issues isn ON t.issue_type=isn.issue_id 
        JOIN incident_names inn ON t.incident_type=inn.incidentId 
        order by t.tid DESC
```

This is the resultant data of the above query.

[image]
[image]

Now I need to compare the `holidays` in above query. And the sample data is,

[image]

If the expected date that am getting in `IF` condition of above query is falls in this `holidays`, I need to update the `sla_name` value with **COUNT OF HOLIDAYS(If startdata and enddate are there, need to count the days between them) + sla_name**.

**If expected date is falls on dates range(start and end dates of holidays), need to calculate the count of days from expected date to end date and update that count in sla_name field**

Is it possible to do this functionality in SQL? I've used the above query as **VIEWS**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `t.sla AS sla_name`, use this expression to determine whether to add the length of the overlapping holiday to the number of days:

```
(
        t.sla + 
        IF(
            DATE_ADD(t.createdAt,INTERVAL (t.sla)+1 DAY) BETWEEN holidays.holiday_date AND holidays.end_date,
            DATEDIFF( holidays.end_date, holidays.holiday_date ), /* add holiday length number of days */
            0 /* no holiday overlap so don't add any days */
        )
) as sla_name
```

You'll also have to join on the holidays table to find the holiday (if any) which overlaps the date in question:

```
JOIN holidays ON ( DATE_ADD(t.createdAt,INTERVAL (t.sla)+1 DAY) BETWEEN holidays.holiday_date and holidays.end_date )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what do I need to do if the date I got from ```DATE_ADD(t.createdAt,INTERVAL (t.sla)+1 DAY)``` is in holidays range and how to update the date ```DATE_ADD(t.createdAt,INTERVAL (t.sla)+1 DAY)``` with the ```enddate+1``` as the new date?

Comment: And I dont need to update the value of  ```sla_name``` field

Comment: The expression I listed first determines how many days to add to `sla_name`: if `DATE_ADD(t.createdAt,INTERVAL (t.sla)+1 DAY) ` falls within a holiday, it adds `DATEDIFF( holidays.end_date, holidays.holiday_date )` days, otherwise it adds 0 days. Your original post said, _"I need to extend the sla_name field value."_, which is exactly what my code is doing. What do you mean by _"I don't need to update the value of sla_name field"_?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sorry for the change in question. I wanted to ask you on if the ```t.createdAt``` falls within holidays, I want to consider the ```holidays.end_date``` as the ```t.createdAt``` so that the ```sla_name``` need not to be changed and expected date would be extended post holidays which means, ```t.createdAt = holidays.end_date+sla_name(tried to explain the logic behind the actual scenario with this expression.)```

Comment: @Aravind So in other words, if `DATE_ADD(t.createdAt,INTERVAL (t.sla)+1 DAY)` falls within a holiday, then `t.createdAt` should evaluate to `holidays.end_date+sla_name`, otherwise `t.createdAt` should remain unchanged?

Comment: Yes..it should evaluate holidays.end_date+sla_name and t.createdAt should not be changed.

Comment: In your `SELECT` clause, change `t.createdAt` to `(
 IF(
  DATE_ADD(t.createdAt,INTERVAL (t.sla)+1 DAY) BETWEEN holidays.holiday_date AND holidays.end_date,
  DATE_ADD(holidays.end_date, INTERVAL sla_name DAY),
  t.createdAt
 )
) AS createdAt`